# ELF link_map when linked as RELRO

Tags: linux, elf, got, plt

When linking a binary with `-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now`, all relocations are performed at start-up before passing control to the binary.

Because of this, there is no need for the `.got.plt` segment.  Normally, a pointer to the linker's `link_map` structure is stored in this segment.

When compiled with full RELRO, where, if anywhere, can a copy of the `link_map` be obtained without consulting other loaded libraries, or `libdl`?

The place one would expect it to be -- in the segment marked with the tag `DT_PLTGOT` -- it does not appear.  Instead, there's just a link back to Program Header of type `PT_DYNAMIC`.  The slot in the segment marked `DT_GOTPLT` starts with the offset of the `DYNAMIC` section, and does not contain any pointers to the link map.

Headers

```
$ readelf -a amd64-pwntest-relro | egrep -i '(_dynamic|pltgot)'
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x202eb8
    48: 0000000000202ca8     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 _DYNAMIC
```

Binary is RELRO

```
$ checksec.sh --file amd64-relro
RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      FILE
Full RELRO      No canary found   NX disabled   PIE enabled     No RPATH   No RUNPATH   amd64-relro
```

GDB shows that the data at the specified offset, at runtime, does not contain a link map pointer.

```
$ gdb ./amd64-relro
gdb-peda$ start
gdb-peda$ vmmap relro
Start              End                Perm      Name
0x0000555555554000 0x0000555555556000 r-xp      /home/user/pwntools-regression/src/amd64-relro
0x0000555555756000 0x0000555555757000 r-xp      /home/user/pwntools-regression/src/amd64-relro
0x0000555555757000 0x0000555555758000 rwxp      /home/user/pwntools-regression/src/amd64-relro
gdb-peda$ telescope 0x0000555555554000+0x202eb8 5
00:0000|  0x555555756eb8 --> 0x202ca8 
01:0008|  0x555555756ec0 --> 0x0 
02:0016|  0x555555756ec8 --> 0x0 
03:0024|  0x555555756ed0 --> 0x7ffff7675870 (<__GI___libc_free>:        mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x33b671]        # 0x7ffff79b0ee8)
04:0032|  0x555555756ed8 --> 0x7ffff79c0430 (<__pthread_create_2_1>:    push   rbp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the binary has a `DT_DEBUG` entry in the `PT_DYNAMIC` area, it will be filled with a pointer to the `r_debug` symbol in the dynamic linker.

```
test:00007F17ED7DDDB0 Elf64_Dyn <DT_SYMENT, 18h>
test:00007F17ED7DDDB0 Elf64_Dyn <DT_DEBUG, offset _r_debug>
test:00007F17ED7DDDB0 Elf64_Dyn <DT_PLTGOT, offset _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>
```

The second field in `r_debug` is the pointer to `link_map`:

```
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 _r_debug dd 1                                    ; r_version
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 db 0, 0, 0, 0
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 dq offset _link_map_head                ; r_map
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 dq offset _dl_debug_state               ; r_brk
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 dd RT_ADD                               ; r_state
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 db 0, 0, 0, 0
debug001:00007F17ED5DC1A0 dq 7F17ED3B8000h                        ; r_ldbase
```

Comment: Bummer that there doesn't appear to be any additional ways for a stripped binary.

Comment: Even stripped binaries have dynamic section, and usually it includes the `DT_DEBUG` entry, so what's the problem?

Comment: After revisiting, it appears that I misunderstood your post.  The `DT_DEBUG` entry is populated at runtime.  I mistook the output of `readelf -a binary` showing `0` for that slot to mean that it didn't contain useful data.  Examining under GDB shows that is it populated.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!  Just landed a pull request for pwntools to take advantage of this.  Saves about thirty seconds (50% of runtime; slow network comms) vs. leaking a GOT pointer into libc and doing a scandown then parsing the elf header.